# C++ equivalent for NSOperation and NSOperationQueue

Tags: c++, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Please advise me to how to achieve NSOperation and NSOperationQueue functionality in C++.

Comment: There isn't such thing in C++, I suggest to use C++11 threads and to implement your own queue class.

Comment: what is c++11 i.e 11 stands for ? Can i use it with c++ ? Do you have some sample how to achieve the above thing using this ?

Comment: @user1908860 - C++11 refers to the 2011 standard for C++. Before 2011 there were no standard C++ threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSOperation` is a class for managing non-critical tasks. You create Operations, and place them on the `NSOperationQueue` and each operation is performed as the app executes.

There is no such "equivalent" in C++. C++ is a language, as `NSOperationQueue` is part of FoundationKit a part of OSX and iOS, a set of Objective-C objects, that aren't part of the objective-c standard.

What you'll need to research is the Android paradigms for doing task concurrency, and use those. Or you can just manually download the assets from the server, in-lieu of any managed task library.

Comment: I need to do more or similar stuff. we don't manual download as we are developing a professional live game. I know NSOperation and NSOperationQueue is part of obj c foundation but my question if we have to achieve similar thing in C++ then how to achieve that ?

Comment: You're not doing something similar in C++. You're doing something similar in Android. C++ is just a language. Look at how Android does concurrent task management, and it should have examples on how to do this in C++.

Answer (score 1):

A rough substitute for NSOperation: [std::packaged_task](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task).